# putting recycler view above bottom navigation

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have a bottom navigation in main activity and what I'm trying to do is to show `recyclerview` above bottom navigation but my problem is bottom navigation is overlapping `recyclerview` and my `recyclerview` is in map fragment so that is why I'm not able to put it above bottom navigation i tried using margin but its cuts the `recyclerview`
my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_picker">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is your **`bottom navigation View`**?

Comment: it is in the main activity and recyclerview in fragment

Comment: anyways i solved the problem

Comment: How about putting in an actual solution instead of just saying "I solved the problem" so people who face this problem know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set `RecyclerView` at the bottom of parent that's why your UI is overlapping.

Try this,

```
android:layout_below="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_above="@+id/yourBottomNavigationView"
```

So that it will not overlap with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
        `android:layout_above="@+id/navigationLayout"`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigationLayout"
    android:id="@+id/item_picker"/>
```

Comment: thanks but i solved the problem and layout above wont work because bottom navigation is in the main activity